# Firebase Crash upload-sym script not run when archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, symbols, firebase-crash-reporting

I am releasing my first beta versions to iTunes and I am using Firebase Crash reporting. I added a script as a build phase to upload the symbols in xcode. It works fine with normal builds but when I archive and upload this build, there are no corresponding symbol files in the Firebase Crash reporting. How can I get this symbol files to load when archiving as well? If that is not possible how can I add them manually?
With first beta release try I got a crash reported which gave me the needed UUID. I then uploaded it manually with:

./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload ServiceAccount.json UUID

But this approach will always be after the fact and doesn't seem scalable.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just in case anybody has the same problem. I have been doing the following. Download the dSYM's files from itunnesconnect and then run: ./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload App-ServiceAccount.json dSYMs/* . This seems to cover most of the UUID. Surprisingly it still sometimes happens that one is not uploaded and then I have to do it manually for that particular UUID.